# 3D objects moving or disapearing when using A-Frame

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

I am trying to add marker-less objects using AR.js and A-Frame, so far I can load the points based on their locations, however, sometimes, the objects (points) would quickly change positions or totally disappear. Below is my code and the picture on how the object is displayed on my phone.

Is there any way to have the objects (points in my case) stay put?

[image]

```
    <!--aframe latest version-->
    <script src='https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.3/aframe.min.js'></script>

    <!--aframe-ar latest version-->
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/2.1.5/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

    <!--three.js-->
    <script>
        THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL = 'https://raw.githack.com/jeromeetienne/ar.js/master/three.js/'
    </script>

    <!--insert style-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>

<!--the interface system using aframe-->
<body style='margin: 0; overflow: hidden;'>

    <div class="content">

        <header class="app-header">

            <!--inside header-->
            <div class="container">

                <!--text instruction-->
                <p><a href="https://xxx.xxx.xxx" style="text-decoration:none">Welcome to GIS AR</a></p>

            <!--end div-->
            </div>

        <!--end header-->
        </header>

    <!--scene for AR enviroment-->
    <a-scene
        vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
        embedded
        arjs='sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth:1280; sourceHeight:960; displayWidth: 1280; displayHeight: 960; debugUIEnabled: false;'>

        <!--point 1-->
           <a-entity 
               gltf-model="./assets/point/scene.gltf" 
               rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" 
               gps-entity-place="latitude: x.xxxxxx; longitude: xxx.xxxxx;" 
               animation-mixer>
                   <a-text
                   value="Object1"
                   z-offset="2"
                   color="blue"
                   scale="7, 7"
                   position="-2.5 10 0"
                   ></a-text>
           </a-entity>

           <!--point 2-->
           <a-entity 
               gltf-model="./assets/point/scene.gltf" 
               rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" 
               gps-entity-place="latitude: x.xxxxxx; longitude: xxx.xxxxx;"  
               animation-mixer>
                   <a-text
                   value="Object2"
                   z-offset="2"
                   color="blue"
                   scale="7, 7"
                   position="-2.5 10 0"
                   ></a-text>
           </a-entity>

           <!--point 3-->
           <a-entity 
               gltf-model="./assets/point/scene.gltf" 
               rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" 
               gps-entity-place="latitude: x.xxxxxx; longitude: xxx.xxxxx;" 
               animation-mixer>
                   <a-text
                   value="Object3"
                   z-offset="2"
                   color="blue"
                   scale="7, 7"
                   position="-2.5 10 0"
                   ></a-text>
           </a-entity>

        <!--camera properties-->
        <a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader></a-camera>

    </a-scene>
```